# Slurm Batch Script Save to Variable or Append

Tags: bash, slurm, hpc, sbatch

I would like to be able to append my slurm batch scripts to my error file. I submit these on the HPC using `sbatch -J "my_run_name" runscript.slurm`. The content of `runscript.slurm` is summarized below.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=%x
#SBATCH --output=%x.o-%j
#SBATCH --error=%x.e-%j
## Other directives...

error_file="$SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR/$SLURM_JOB_NAME.e-$SLURM_JOB_ID"
main="/path/to/main/file"

# set parameters, then call main function
$main --opt1 $opt1 --opt2 $opt2

# Last line of script
scontrol write batch_script $SLURM_JOB_ID $error_file
```

Unfortunately this overwrites all the other content I've accumulated in my `error_file` throughout my long running calculations (lots of log statements on progress) with `runscript.slurm`

I'm wondering if it is possible to *append* `runscript.slurm` to `error_file` rather than overwrite all existing content in `error_file`.

On a related point - is it possible to dump the contents of `runscript.slurm` into a bash variable which I can then pass to my `main` function (that way I can save `runscript.slurm` as an additional field in the calculation result). Hopefully that question makes sense.

Comment: Why don't you use a shell redirection to append to the error file instead of giving SLURM the file where to output the script??

Comment: @Poshi because I didn't know about the shell redirection, that's why! But now I do, and it works great. Thank you. Also to anyone else who comes along, to save the output to a variable you can do `batch_script=$(scontrol write batch_script $SLURM_JOB_ID -)`

Comment: Redirections are pretty standard and common, but nobody is born with all the knowledge. Happy to see it worked for you :-)
On the other hand, I didn't realized the existence of the `write batch_script` command for `scontrol`, so thanks for the knowledge! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
scontrol write batch_script $SLURM_JOB_ID - >> $error_file
```

Instead of giving SLURM the file where to store the script, you can take its output and redirect it to the file of interest in append mode.